# Backbone routing: Are server modifications necessary?

Tags: backbone.js, routes

Right now, I'm using hash routes in my Backbone application.  I'd like to use full routes, so I would have a URL that looks like (with `leads` being the page in my SPA):

`leads/#/main-contact`

rather than

`leads#main-contact`

I added this line:

`Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/"});`

But the route `/main-contact` doesn't work.  I understand I may have to do some server modifications.  Can someone tell me what's involved in getting this to work?

Comment: As far as I'm aware of, the part after the "#" sign of the query is not send to the server. This is purely a "placeholder" for the client to process. So you can not have routes like "leads/#/something"

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to have your server-side serve up a page which contains your router code regardless of the path given.

/leads/* ---> leads.html

I cannot be more specific than that as the mechanism by which one does this on the server-side is specific on what server-side technology you're using.

Answer (score 0):

try main-contact without the / as your route in your backbone router

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Rewrite rules to fetch the file (The file that handles your routing logic)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you need to ensure that the server handles requests against `lead/`, ie forwarding those requests to `lead.php`or similar. How this is done is usually dependent on the server software and not the server-side language used. For example, a quick google search turned up the following links:

1. [Remove trailing slash using apache mod_rewrite](http://jenstinfors.com/2011/04/07/remove-trailing-slash-using-apache-mod_rewrite/)
2. [How do I remove trailing slashes from a URL when using Apache's default directory index file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/250161/how-do-i-remove-trailing-slashes-from-a-url-when-using-apaches-default-director)

For `Backbone.Router`you don't need to do anything. `Backbone.history` automatically removes any leading slashes and trailing whitespace from the route; ie `main-contact` will match both `#main-contact` and `#/main-contact`. Here is a short example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/help">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="message"></div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/documentcloud/underscore/master/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/documentcloud/backbone/master/backbone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                "home": "home",
                "help": "help",
                "about": "about"
            },
            home: function () { this.msg("home"); },
            help: function () { this.msg("help"); },
            about: function () {this.msg("about"); },
            msg: function(m) { $("#message").text(m); }
        });

        new MyRouter();
        Backbone.history.start();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: I have only tested the above example by running it from a local file.